# setAutoCommit() does nothing

Tags: android, ormlite

I followed the instructions in [How to use Dao.setAutoCommit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542413/how-to-use-dao-setautocommit) to try to disable autocommit so I could run commits in batches.

Whenever I would actually try to run the code, my program would keep track of how many times I had called create and similar operations on DAOs, and when it was greater than the batch size, would call dao.commit()... and then I would get this error (SaveJsonParser is the name of the class with the code):

06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): java.lang.Runtime

```
Exception: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no transaction pending
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(SQLiteDatabase.java:673)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.commit(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:77)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.commit(BaseDaoImpl.java:811)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.visitsanantonio.save.data.SaveJsonParser.commitCategories(SaveJsonParser.java:412)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.visitsanantonio.save.data.SaveJsonParser.parseDeal(SaveJsonParser.java:278)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.visitsanantonio.save.data.SaveJsonParser.parseNewUpdatedDeals(SaveJsonParser.java:233)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.visitsanantonio.save.data.SaveJsonParser$JsonParsingTask.doInBackground(SaveJsonParser.java:479)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at com.visitsanantonio.save.data.SaveJsonParser$JsonParsingTask.doInBackground(SaveJsonParser.java:1)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-08 17:18:50.866: E/AndroidRuntime(30993):    ... 4 more
```

After some experimentation, it looked like my code was not actually disabling autoCommit, as shown by this sanitized, truncated example run in a background thread:

```
conn = dao.startThreadConnection();
Log.e(TAG, "dao auto commit: " + dao.isAutoCommit(conn));
dao.setAutoCommit(conn, false);
Log.e(TAG, "dao auto commit: " + dao.isAutoCommit(conn));
```

Checking the logs, I see that both log lines read "true." I am not actually changing whether or not it autocommits. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998630/how-to-disable-autocommit-in-sqlite4java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong aside from (possible) not reading the [Javadocs on `setAutoCommit()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#setAutoCommit%28com.j256.ormlite.support.DatabaseConnection,%20boolean%29).  It states:

> This may not be supported by all database types.

and.

> **WARNING:** Chances are you should be using the dao.callBatchTasks(Callable) instead of this method unless you know what you are doing.

Unfortunately, one of the database types that does not support auto-commit is SQLite under Android.  In the Android database connection, the code is a no-op.  I did this on purpose but I'll go back and verify that [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is correct and that Android doesn't support it.

If you want to run a number of commands in batch mode, I'd recommend using the [`dao.callBatchTasks(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/docs/batch) instead.  I'll update the javadocs to explain this better and test to make sure that current ORMlite code is right to not use auto-commit under Android.  Something like:

```
accountDao.callBatchTasks(connectionSource,
  new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws SQLException {
        // insert a number of accounts at once
        for (Account account : accountsToInsert) {
           // update our account object
           accountDao.create(account);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Auto-commit not working under Android: first, if you could update the documentation to explicitly state that, that would be wonderful. Second, would you mind updating your answer to my earlier question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542413/how-to-use-dao-setautocommit where you instructed me to use setAutoCommit() for Android?
The callBatchTasks() documentation says "NOTE: If neither auto-commit nor transactions are supported by the database type then this may do nothing." does this work on Android?

Comment: Sorry for the contradictory statements @Chad.  I'll fix my other answer.

Comment: It should work since it will use transactions that definitely _do_ work.  I also know of people who have gotten performance improvements with transactions.  I'll do some tests.

Comment: I just did 1000 inserts into a table under my simulator.  Without `callBatchTasks()` it took 6.2secs.  With too 1.7secs.  Not hugely faster but some improvements.

Comment: @ChadSchultz After thinking about it a sec, I've added support for auto-commit using transactions to the Android connection code.  Should have done this long ago.  It will be in 4.42.  Let me know if you want a snapshot release.

Comment: Thanks for the modification, Gray. I found another approach (see other answer) and don't feel like changing all my code back at this point, but that will be very useful for future projects! :)

Comment: @Gray I see that you added the auto-commit for android in 2012 and then removed the Dao.setAutoCommit method as being deprecated in 2016. I suppose there is a good reason and another way to achieve this: so now, what should we do for Android?

Comment: I just changed it to take a connection @OroshiX.  See: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#setAutoCommit(com.j256.ormlite.support.DatabaseConnection,%20boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution and method of Gray...

```
accountDao.callBatchTasks(connectionSource,
  new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws SQLException {
        // insert a number of accounts at once
        for (Account account : accountsToInsert) {
           // update our account object
           accountDao.create(account);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

I wrote a static method serving as a generic version:

```
public static <T, K> void batchCommit(final List<T> objectsToCommit, final Dao<T, K> dao) throws Exception {
    dao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            for (T obj : objectsToCommit) {
                dao.create(obj);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
'DaoUtil'.batchCommit(accountsToinsert, accountDao);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sanitized version of what I finally came up with to process database requests in batches. This approach doesn't crash, and hopefully it actually works for processing database requests in batches (instead of either committing each object separately or trying to accumulate a very large of transactions for a single commit).

```
final static Integer BATCH_SIZE = 100;

int index = 0;

public int processInBatch(final Collection objectsToProcess)
            throws java.sql.SQLException {

    final int len = objectsToProcess.length();

    Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            int endIndex = index + BATCH_SIZE;
            if (endIndex > len) {
                endIndex = len;
            }
            for (; index < endIndex; index++) {
                MyObject o = objectsToProcess.get(index);
                try {
                    dao.createOrUpdate(o);
                } catch (java.sql.SQLException se) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error while attempting to add or update myobject with id of " + o.getId(), se);
                }
            }
        return null;
        }
    };

    ConnectionSource source = databaseHelper.getConnectionSource();
    while (index < len) {
        TransactionManager.callInTransaction(source, callable);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work Chad.  You can take a look at the `testInsertInBatches()` method in this test for a way to do it inline if you care: http://goo.gl/ISQvh